# Deleting with a stored procedure and multiple parameters in SQL statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedures, and have made one that deletes from a table when two of the non-unique key columns are equal to the two parameters passed into it.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `sp_deleteTempRecords`(IN `schoolID` SMALLINT(6), IN `testID` INT(11)) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
DELETE FROM tbl_temp WHERE tbl_temp.testID=testID AND tbl_temp.schoolID=schoolID; 
END
```

However, when executing the procedure it does not delete anything. If I change the SQL statement to just delete the primary key, then it works (For that I have to change the INs to receive the tempID, INT(11). If I enter the SQL directly in phpMyAdmin using two values for the schoolID and testID parameter values, it runs and deletes everything fine.

I have only deleted records with a stored procedure using the primary key before, so do not understand why it wouldn't delete with other parameters, when executing the SQL code directly would. Thanks!

Comment: Must work. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2202f1f8164d086ac60f00e04e541a79 Check the values provided. *If I enter the SQL directly in phpMyAdmin using two values for the schoolID and testID parameter values, it runs and deletes everything fine.* What if you call this SP "directly in phpMyAdmin using two values for the schoolID and testID parameter values"?

Comment: Hi @Akina thanks for looking and re-creating it. Your prompt made me look at the parameters being passed into it and I realised my code is passing the parameters in the wrong order to what is declared in the SP.  Silly mistake, but good to learn from! Thanks.